# Another doGet() issue with Google Apps Script - "Unknown macro doGet" error

Tags: api, google-apps-script

I'am obviously new to Google Apps Script, nevertheless I have some experience in coding in C, PHP and Java. Since we would like to create a small CRM in our company with Google Apps Script, we need to create an application with a form available on Google Sites. I've been searching an answer for this problem a long time, I haven't unfortunately found any answer. I have a code like this:

```
var klienci_id = new Array(100);
var klienci_nazwa = new Array(100);
var klienci_adres = new Array(100);
var klienci_osoba = new Array(100);
var klienci_telefon = new Array(100);
var klienci_email = new Array(100);

function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

   // hello world label
  var helloworldLabel = app.createLabel("I love Apps  Script!").setStyleAttribute("fontSize","16px");

  // add the label to the app container
  app.add(helloworldLabel);

  return app;
}


function main() {

 var klienci = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0ArsOaWajjzv9dEdGTUZCWFc1NnFva05uWkxETVF6Q0E");

 var kuchnia_polska = klienci.getSheetByName("Kuchnia polska");

 var dane = kuchnia_polska.getRange("D7:F22");

doGet();

}
```

And everytime I try to publish it and enter the given link I get the error "Unknown macro doGet". I know this is a common problem when somebody doesn't use doGet() function but I do - and it still doesn't work. I also believe that Google should create a thorought documentation on Google Apps Script, which would work the way the Unix manual does, since I just cannot get through all these strange pages of goddamn help :) It's neither a Windows help, nor a good manual ;)

Regards,
Kamil

Answer (score 6):

I have a suspicion that you made a "version" once, published the app, went to the "real" link and not the "development" link, and then added the doGet() function. When you make a version, it freezes the code at that time. The version that the app is published at is the version of the code that will run at the "real" link (what you give users), which allows you to keep editing the code without disturbing existing users of your app. There is a special "development" link given to you in the publish dialog that always refers to the most recent version of the code, but which will only work for you and no one else.

Comment: Yes, you are right :) I just came back here to write the same since I have discovered it a moment ago and I see you found out the problem. Thanks for answer and sorry for taking your time with such a stupid issue. 

Yes, there is a link in the Publish dialog under the words of "Test web app for your latest code.". I though it's some kind of help or sth :P

Comment: @Corey : when you say "always refers to the most recent version of the code" do you mean the last "save" or the las "version" ? I think it is just "save" but would like you to confirm ;-) - Also, do you agree with my answer below or am I wrong somehow ? (I'd love to get your opinion too :-). Thanks

Comment: There is one example of when you'd want something to call doGet(), and that's exactly what the original questioner did in the sample - to be able to show the same app both inside a Spreadsheet and as a standalone app.

Comment: I never thought about doing this but to make it work shouldn't the "main function" end like this ? `doGet();
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication()
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(app)
}`

Comment: Yes, you'd need to have show(doGet()) or something equivalent. I use this pattern while testing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm affraid there is a little misunderstanding on your side concerning the use of the 'doGet()' function.  When you want to run an application as a webapp, the [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp?hl=fr-FR#Deploying) says indeed that it must contain a doGet function but what it doesn't say explicitely is that this function is supposed to be the starting point of the whole app, ie the function that the url will call in the first place.  So it doesn't make much sense to have the doGet function called from a so called "main" function since the "main" function is not the main function...

I cannot imagine right now a situation where some function calls the doGet function since every function in the script is called initially (directly or indirectly) from this doGet function.... in fact the 'end' of any other function in the script 'returns' to the doGet initial function. Well this is maybe not absolutely true in every case but it gives you the general idea about how it works.

I'm hoping this is clear enough and, to return to your code snippet, if you remove the doGet(e) call, it will ideed show a nice "I love Apps  Script!" but it will never do anything else, certainly not see the "main" function.

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your code here https://script.google.com/macros/d/MJ80AK8t7kbgDcC-NaLPYvH797_hv7HHb/edit?template=app&folder=0AKGkLMU9sHmLUk9PVA

and when deployed as a web app appears to work https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxOiaukLt7P4pIm7bms7aU16uEo6FuZ-MNOh0tSqUwr/dev

Only thing I can think of is there is something else in your code not copied into the snippet that is throwing the exception.

[Just before the GUI Builder was published I came up with [Creating a framework for custom form interfaces using Google Apps Script](http://mashe.hawksey.info/2011/05/work-in-progress-google-spreadsheetsites-flexible-event-booking-form/) which might help you with your project]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for help. **Serge**, yes, it's really not obvious what the structure of Google Apps Scripts should be. They are based on JavaScript, however, due to lack of HTML in the code they have completely different flow - so naturally, there has to be a main function which is executed first. And of course in every programming environment it has to have a different name to make it more distinguishable ;-)

I created a new copy of my application, not changing the code completely - deployed it and it works beautifuly. Since I haven't changed anything in access options, it's quite strange that two applications with the same code and the same options don't give the same result. I think it may be a kind of the environment flaw, maybe someone from Google should look at this :)

Here's the link to the script, I've set access to "Anyone with the link".

https://script.google.com/a/macros/foodbroker.pl/s/AKfycbwk2IM-rIYLhQl6HOlbppwGOnw4Ik_kH7ixbaSNVxIE-QR7cq8/exec

Comment: This link is giving me a nice 'unknown macro doGet'. ...:-)

Comment: Yeah Im having the same problem -_-