# Google App Script: ContentService web app usage

Tags: google-apps-script, google-gadget

I am stuck for 3 days now trying to get 2 google gadgets to reliably communicate on a google site to exchange anonymous user session information based on UiInstance.getId() value. Since gadget-to-gadget pubsub feature is deprecated, I am trying to use the ContentService in the server gadget to service a doPost request from originating from the client gadget - the idea being, I will store the session information in a server gadget and pull the data into gadgets on other pages in the site - not sure if this is possible.

BUT, I am stuck even trying to tinker with the various examples on the ContentService posted on StackOverflow. I am stuck at a very basic step and unable to proceed beyond the super simple server code below. I am not able to figure out what would the URL of the server gadget I need to use from my client gadget. I seem to be getting confusing results.

Server code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
  output.setContent("Hi from ContentServer!");
  return output;
}
```

Steps I followed:

1) Published the server as a web app and set it up so anyone/anonymous can access it.

2) The publish window popup says the gadget is available at 
    https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyIa07kBC-gqG0nJq3Up5GzUntbTaYcM1KmaYF7vQvFIWN_qxA/exec

3) If I use a browser to open the link, I get "Unknown macro doGet".

4) If I click on the link given by "Test web app for your latest code." from the publish window popup, it seems to take me to 
https://script.googleusercontent.com/echo?user_content_key=WwuWW_Hhp2wlHpHWsX-qAwu7jtKrwlt1fkkesojKEWeJXKm5AoUOhuRHxu4RIHLrWovOBUsHhOB3No0RYr05RE4tWtliFlXKm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnG5I1NuldcVdfVF6dOROkmljXtr0dWIARhfeRbamxWJIIJeMc5tWnrGPpehwqDtynQ&lib=MfYY3NqJ0IdcpreIfwd3uwgmzn1S_adTp

The above link from step 4 works from a browser BUT its very flaky from my client gadget! It seems to work the very first time I version and publish it but returns raw HTML if I update the version even once.

I believe I am missing some trivial step OR there is a serious version control or deployment bug with web-app gadgets.

I have checked out the following threads on stackoverflow that were pretty useful.
[How to use ContentService and doPost to create a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935420/how-to-use-contentservice-and-dopost-to-create-a-rest-api)

KamilG seems to have overcome the issue here [Another doGet() issue with Google Apps Script - "Unknown macro doGet" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487439/another-doget-issue-with-google-apps-script-unknown-macro-doget-error)

But its very wobbly for me and I am unable to pin down any reliable procedure the get the ContentService working from my server gadget.

Any help and explanation will be much appreciated.

Here is my client gadget code.

```
function doGet(e) {
//  var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyIa07kBC-gqG0nJq3Up5GzUntbTaYcM1KmaYF7vQvFIWN_qxA/exec";
  //var url = "https://script.googleusercontent.com/echo?user_content_key=9tzQxTSPm8ADsHKl4bCg6ru-49C19kYZCW8IRuWiWi-Xe_lTlQZS4xq8v5aPqjR6Ybj7-xjjJXyQPhOH0T3KFtJUtXc7U-Dkm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnJlCLn2pnKC0O1TYz53ccgjxtVC9ccM8kFegFJ0AJSK_YP_ylqfjfm1EU_BUbZUu-88PMDJ6xpj8&lib=MTLHdJRs3UPYj3bYgbhBNnNGZ7UmftE34";
  var url = "https://script.googleusercontent.com/echo?user_content_key=LvlwGkBktQ732xyD1HJbh5OhMsuhkidt_rOovw-olm-wJQF4LlErMDSxsfDaAb4UBYqOeTI3-8soIBj-KaOCDi0WlUav4Nl_m5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnG5I1NuldcVdfVF6dOROkmljXtr0dWIARhfeRbamxWJIIJeMc5tWnrGPpehwqDtynQ&lib=MfYY3NqJ0IdcpreIfwd3uwgmzn1S_adTp";

  // WELL ONE OF THE URLS WORKS FROM ABOVE!!! BUT ONLY TILL I UPDATE THE SERVER WEB APP VERSION :(

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("ClientService Client test");
  app.setStyleAttribute("background", "azure");

  var fetchMethod = 'get';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {method: fetchMethod});

  //var lbl = app.createHTML("<b>Response :</b>" + response.getContentText());
  var lbl = app.createTextArea().setText(response.getContentText());

  var lbl1 = app.createHTML("<b>Response code :</b> "
                            + response.getResponseCode()); 

  app.add(lbl);
  app.add(lbl1);
  return app;
}
```

Help needed please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functioning as intended for the most part, but I think there might be some alternatives.

1. Regarding your point #3 - That URL above works. There must have been something wrong with the version you tested (perhaps you didn't declare doGet correctly?).
2. The link from #4 is a one time use redirect that happens when you Content Service. See the redirect section [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/content_service?hl=en) all the way at the bottom. This link is short lived and you might be fast enough to catch it in a browser but a another separate calling client (the "gadget") might not be so lucky. So you should never call the googlecontentservice.com link directly.
3. Regarding the overall issue of flakiness of ContentService, I have not seen this. If I properly use the /exec link and then properly increment the version after every appropriate change things work as expected for me.

I built a simple web app accessing your Content Service and things seem to work fine for me consistently. See below. The code looks identical to yours but I am using the first url.

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw6nlfv5ME6F3Z2WBdW24YAgfQm_E5gYV0xrMDvDwZLrX7PdMU/exec

As an alternative - is there a reason you are doing a server side UrlFetch from one script to another? If you can fetch the data server side, can you just perform the logic of the content script w/in the UI script?

Comment: Thanks Arun, I see consistent behavior with your pointers. I guess using the googleusercontent URL led to my confusion.
Basically I need session management for anonymous user. The Browser and Session classes dont have unique key to track a session for the server. Is there a way to track sessions between site pages without requiring the user to login via a google account?
I began to explore the ContentService doPost/doGet APIs to see if I can achieve the above. Please provide any alternate ideas I can pursue if ContentService is not the appropriate for this. Also I have edited the title.