# Enabling an application to use a Google AppScript Webservice as a proxy to a Gmail account

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, authorization

I've been trying to integrate my application (ruby) with a Google AppScript (published as a Web Application with access level as 'only me') on behalf of a Google Apps account for quite some time, but I can't get a handle of it. Maybe I'm missing a key concept here or that sort of authentication/authorization isn't available when making requests in the background.

The script works fine when I'm logged in to gmail and access the script endpoint. I can also successfully connect to it using a sinatra application authenticated with openid.

I've already tried to use google-api-ruby-client, but I can't get the authorization scope right (service name). I've also tried clientlogin in gdata-ruby-util, to use Gmail login/password and get an authorization error message when trying to fetch from the script url.

Is it doable? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Contentservice in Apps Script (which I think you are using to create your webservice) doesn't provide any authentication mechanism. If you are accessing it from a server side script, you can use a token string which is known by your webservice app and your server to provide a level of security to your publicly accessible webservice.

Here are some similar discussion

- [How to use Google Apps Script ContentService as a REST server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475972/how-to-use-google-apps-script-contentservice-as-a-rest-server)
- [Google App Script: ContentService web app usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308106/google-app-script-contentservice-web-app-usage)

Comment: That's unfortunate, indeed. There it goes an elegant solution to my problem. My intention was to develop an AppScript along with a ruby gem to interact with gmail without IMAP. Requiring users to set a token inside the script side seems cumbersome and lacks the level of security their used to when dealing with their google products. Thank you, anyway.